# Pie Chart - Problems with font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I am now working on a pie chart and i have a problem about the size of the number. Is there any way to make only the "1%" and "2%" smaller so that i can be seen clearly in the chart. (or make an arrow only on these two arcs)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\tikzset{lines/.style={draw=none},}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \pie[style={lines}, text=legend, rotate=220]{58/SHI, 5/General government, 13/Private households (OOP), 4/Employers, 9/PHI, 2/Statutory accident insurance, 1/Statutory Pension insurance, 8/Social long-term care insurance}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can get a hint from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338528/how-to-put-small-numbers-outside-the-pie-slices-without-making-a-mess?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps consider moving the thin-sliced labels outside of the chart: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595500/put-small-numbers-outside-of-a-pgf-pie-chart, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594973/put-percentages-outside-of-pie-chart, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320918/pie-graph-with-outside-text

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: pie charts are generally terrible (unless comparing pieces of pie). Just use a horizontal bar chart.

Comment: just curious that how an user with 1 reputation can start a bounty ?

Answer (score 1):

look for the ".65" and change at will.
The code is basically just copied from that package and changed in these few lines there.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\tikzset{lines/.style={draw=none},}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]

\makeatletter
% args:
% #1: begin angle
% #2: end angle
% #3: number
% #4: label
% #5: explode
% #6: fill color
% #7: radius
% #8: center
\def\pgfpie@slice#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*(#1)+0.5*(#2)}
  \let\pgfpie@midangle\pgfmathresult

  \path (#8) -- ++({\pgfpie@midangle}:{#5}) coordinate (pgfpie@O);

  \pgfmathparse{(#7)+(#5)}
  \let\pgfpie@radius\pgfmathresult

  % slice
  \draw[line join=round,fill={#6},\pgfpie@style] (pgfpie@O) -- ++({#1}:{#7}) arc ({#1}:{#2}:{#7}) -- cycle;

  \pgfmathparse{min(((#2)-(#1)-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  \pgfmathparse{(max(\pgfmathresult,-0.5) + 0.8)*(#7)}
  \let\pgfpie@innerpos\pgfmathresult

  \pgfpie@ifx\pgfpie@text\pgfpie@text@inside{%
    % label and number together
    \path (pgfpie@O) -- ++({\pgfpie@midangle}:{\pgfpie@innerpos}) node[align=center]
    {\pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@labeltext{#4}\\\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}};
  }{%
    % label
    \pgfpie@ifhidelabel{}{%
      \pgfpie@iflegend{}{%
        \path (pgfpie@O) -- ++ ({\pgfpie@midangle}:{\pgfpie@radius})
        node[inner sep=0, \pgfpie@text={\pgfpie@midangle:#4}]{};
      }%
    }%

    % number
    \path (pgfpie@O) -- ++({\pgfpie@midangle}:{\pgfpie@innerpos}) node
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{1}\OR\equal{#3}{2}}{%
            \scalebox{.65}{\pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}}%
        }{%
            \pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}%
        }%
    };
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[style={lines}, text=legend, rotate=220]{58/SHI, 5/General government, 13/Private households (OOP), 4/Employers, 9/PHI, 2/Statutory accident insurance, 1/Statutory Pension insurance, 8/Social long-term care insurance};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```