# Put small numbers outside of a pgf-pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I have a pgf-pie chart and some of the values are so small that the number does not display correctly. Therefore I would like to put them outside of the chart, as seen on the second picture I found on the internet.

MWE of my chart

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[sum=auto,text=legend]{10/A, 1/B, 29/C, 43/D, 16/E}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Pie}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is what my chart looks like

[image: My pie]

This is the picture of how I imagine my the numbers outside could look like I found but obviously, I'd like to keep the legend and all other formatting.

[image: The other chart]

How can that be done?

Comment: If you believe the duplicate answer I cited does not address your situation, let me know I can label your question as not a duplicate.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It is very similar but the solution given in the question you mentioned doesn't really work well with absolute (non-percentage) values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm learning `pgf-pie` as I go, and adapted from my answer here, [Put percentages outside of pie chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594973/put-percentages-outside-of-pie-chart).  But in this case, I had to learn to use the `sum=` qualifier to specify charts with a total other than 100.  That was especially important here, because the method I used was to superimpose 3 pie charts: the first chart plots all 5 slices with one label arrangement, the second plot superimposes 2 slices with a different label arrangement, and the last plot does a single slice with another labeling arrangement.

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[sum=auto,text=legend]{10/A, 1/B, 29/C, 43/D, 16/E}
% COMMENT EDIT: 10+1+29+43+16 = 99 !!!
\pie[sum=99, hide number]{10/, 1/1}
\pie[sum=99]{10/}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Pie}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's smart! thanks

Comment: Nice solution. I wondered why you used `sum=99` instead of `sum=100` and I noticed a weird gap when using a sum of 100. Did you find this by try and error, or is it a logical reason to do so?

Comment: @SebGlav 10+1+29+43+16 = 99.  The weird gap was caused because the the first chart's pies were 10/99 and 1/99 fractions. If you set sum=100 on subsequent chart, then the slices were .1 and .01 fractions.

Comment: Wow! And I'm a math teacher! I didn't even think about summing all the figures, and thought it was percentages... Sorry for the dumb question. So you could have used `sum=99` instead of `sum=auto` in the first pie (I tried, obviously). Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: @SebGlav I fell down the same hole, until I realized that `sum=` could take something other than `auto`.  Don't feel bad.  It would have been more obvious if the totals summed to something quite distinct, like 42.